# Bayesian networks for one-class classification

Tags: r, classification, graphical-model, bayesian-network, one-class

From the definition of one-class classification in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification#cite_note-1):

> In machine learning, one-class classification, also known as unary
>   classification or class-modelling, tries to identify objects of a
>   specific class amongst all objects, by learning from a training set
>   containing only the objects of that class.

And:

> A similar problem is PU learning, in which a binary classifier is
>   learned in a semi-supervised way from only positive and unlabeled
>   sample points.

I'm looking for examples of this in the context of Bayesian Networks. I imagine a case in which for one node of the network there are only positive examples available, but a binary classifier is desired. I want to know of any examples of such a case, if possible with associated code. I'm mostly using the bnlearn package in R but I could use anything.

**Note:** although this has been used extensively for outlier detection, the problem I would like to tackle isn't really an outlier detection one. I want to model animal species distribution and I only have positive examples: places where an animal species was observed. But naturally cannot be sure of the species absence if it wasn't observed during a certain sampling effort.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simple, yet actionable approach:

- Collect your data, preprocess them to get categorical features $X$.
- Create, tune, optimize the Bayesian network for $X$ with bnlearn. As a result we have practically a probability distribution $p(X)$.
- Take all your observations and calculate their likelihoods $L_i=p(x_i)$.
- Based on the likelihoods define a threshold $\theta$ for false negatives, i.e. if the desired [sensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is e.g. 95%, you should take the likelihood that corresponds to the 5th quantile.

The resulting classifier is then: $p(X)>\theta$.

The trick is that you never know how similar are the unobserved counter examples. However, based on some ex-post observations, you can tune the threshold also with the respect to [specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Specificity).

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'm testing it out right now. Do you by any chance know of literature were an approach like this has been used? Thank you!

Comment: It seems it's not possible, out of the box, to fit a bayesian network with a node with only 1 level: Error in check.data(data, allow.missing = TRUE) : 
  variable Species must have at least two levels. How would you fit the bn in this context?

Comment: I would not involve Species in the model.